# Make specific dates in customCalendar disable android

Tags: android, date, decorator, simpledateformat, android-calendar

I have problem in custom calendar in decorator, I am trying to disable specific dates, I have string ArrayList with specific dates in the format "05/03/2017" and I want to make these dates in the array list disable

I tried this code but its not work

```
String d1="05/03/2017";
String d2="08/03/2017";
String d3="12/03/2017";

ArrayList<String> bookDates = new ArrayList<>();
bookDates.add(d1);
bookDates.add(d2);
bookDates.add(d3);
```

In this class I made loop to let the dates that inside the array list disable

```
  private class DisabledColorDecorator implements DayDecorator {
    @Override
    public void decorate(DayView dayView) {

        SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        if (CalendarUtils.isPastDay(dayView.getDate())) {
            int color = Color.parseColor("#a9afb9");
            dayView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }


        for (int i =0; i<bookDates.size();i++) {
            try {
                if (curFormater.parse(bookDates.get(i))== dayView.getDate())       {
                    int color = Color.parseColor("#a9afb9");
                    dayView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or if there any way to make specific dates disable?
If anybody know please help me, I search a lot and not able to find solution

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am answering My question so I left this code and used another library called caldroid its custom calendar. it helps to make selected dates and disable dates easily and also can change the color of dates and everything..

if anyone needs to know about it and use it, you can find it from this link
[roomorama/Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid#client-can-customize-look-and-feel-of-almost-all-views)

hope this may help someone